# Overlapping PNG images without using CSS position:relative

Tags: html, css, image, position

I have a bunch of PNG images that will be placed one after the other.  Most of them are rectangles but a few of them have part of the image sticking above the top of the rest of the image.  I am hoping to have that part overlap onto the image above it.  I can use position:relative; bottom:50px; to move the image up to overlap the image above it, but then there is a gap between that image and the one below it.  Can anyone thing of a way to have those images overlap without leaving a gap below?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *negative* `margin-top` value for that.

(I added some `opacity` to the second element in my snippet to make the overlapping more obvious by letting the top element shine through a bit)

```css
.x {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  background: yellow;
}
.b {
  background: blue;
  margin-top: -50px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.c {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="x a"></div>
<div class="x b"></div>
<div class="x c"></div>
```